# AWS EC2 Instance rejected public key

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, public-key, connection-refused

I just launched a AWS EC2 Image today, I got to authenticate successfully and I did the following changes:

- `sudo yum update`
- Install Oracle JDK 8_92 using wget
- Remove all other java options
- export `JAVA_HOME` and alter `bash_profile` to do the same thing
- Change locale to Mexico
- Change timezone to Mexico/General
- Download Payara build 163 (`wget`) Rename it.

Then I ask the instance to reboot, now I can´t authenticate. It refuse "our public key" any ideas?

I think it might have to do with `sudo yum update`, but not sure.

Comment: You don't authenticate with a public key, you authenticate with a certificate based on your private key. Double check the IP address in the AWS console, it may have changed.

Comment: Double checked, I found the problem, I was making my user directory (/home/ec2-user) with 777 privileges that messed everything

Comment: Yep that'll do it. Suggest you delete your question or create your own answer and accept it, so people don't bother to try to help.

Comment: Can you explain why?  Please

Comment: Right now the question isn't marked answered, so people will come in and try to help. That wastes peoples time. If you want to respect the people who spend their own time to help others you mark questions as answered once you have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed, the answer has that I was making my user directory (/home/ec2-user) with 777 privileges that messed everything